# Python: How to fit curve by user defined function?

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scipy, curve-fitting

[image: Curve Fitting via Optimization]

Hey everyone,

To show you my question I have drawn a picture. As you can see, the curve 'A(m)' with red color is target function. Its expression is known.

The curve with green color is objected function 'f' with 4 parameter a, b, c, d.
This function is very complicated (the expression has more than 4000 strings ) and is generated by a program.

**My question is how to find the best fitting parameters a, b, c, d with another additional condition:

f >= A**

***The major difficulty is the speed, as mentioned, the function is too complicated***

I tried to use nested loops to find the best parameters, but each loop need a few minutes to run and then failed.

I am new to python. Any suggestions and ideas will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you all in advance！

Comment: Start with something like this: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.minimize.html

Comment: You've tagged this with `machine-learning`. Does that mean you don't want to use `scipy.optimize`, and instead want to train a network to do this? (And, if so, why?)

Comment: @abarnert before asking in stackoverflow I have searched in google. Some people solve similar problem by using machine-learning. For me, if it can be solved efficiently, I can try them both, whether machine learning or scipy. so I have both tagged.  As I mentioned， the major difficulty is speed, because the function is too complicated..

Comment: Slow function-evaluation always should point you to derivative-free optimization / black-box optimization (with costly evaluation). There are other things to reason about: deterministic/stochastic, maybe your external code is iterative and so on. Checkout some surveys googling the keywords / or check on google scholar. Most approaches are based on some smoothness-assumptions and  surrogate models (a low number of func-eval is a design-characteristic!). scipy won't be much of a help there.

Comment: Just to clarify, is this what you want? Choose parameters a, b, c and d to minimize some error measure (sum([f(a, b, c, d, m)-A(m)]**2)?) subject to the requirement that f(a, b, c, d, m) >= A(m), for some set of values of m? And you want to do this with a minimal number of calls to f()? Is that right? In particular, are you trying to match A(m) while also requiring that your function never falls below A(m)?

Comment: @MatthiasFripp yes,  you are right.  You can think of A(m) as Worst Case. The work is to make f approach to A(m), and still within the Worst Case (never falls below A(m))

Comment: @sun0727 I think @sascha's comment above gives more insight than I can. One derivative-free method I have used is particle swarm optimization, but I don't think of that as using a small number of evaluations of the minimized function. One thing I would say (which you may already know) is that you could think of this as choosing a, b, c and d to minimize g(a, b, c, d), where g(a, b, c, d) is equal to `sum(f(a, b, c, d, m) - A(m) if f >= A else C * (A - f) for m in M)`, where C is a large penalty term. This would be an unconstrained optimization problem, which various tools seek to solve.

Comment: Well,  a general problem here is --- if `f` is so complicated that you cannot provide restrictions in analytical form--- that at best you can say that `f > A` for your points of evaluation. There still can be infinite points in between where this is not true.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In scipy you have the optimize module that allows you to perform non linear optimization over a list of parameters, you can also define constrains to be respected by the optimizer. You can hence define a loss function as the difference between the user function and the known function and minize such difference over the given parameters. See: https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.html